# Update label text in Viewcontroller from Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My question is similar to the one as here: [Update label.text at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854831/update-label-text-at-runtime)

I have a viewcontroller that contains a tableview with some textfields. When the user enters the quantity and amount in the perspective textfields I want to update a label outside the tableview after I press return on the final keyboard during at runtime

After doing some research I realize that this will get some in the textfieldDidEndEditing function of the textfield delegate in the cell itself but how will i access the label text from the viewcontroller so that i can update it? I will provide the code I have below.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MaterialsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsDescription: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsAmount: UITextField!

    func saveMaterialsData() {
        let saveMaterials = SPMaterialsRequest()
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsDescription!.text, forKey: "materialDescriptiopn")
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsQuantity!.text, forKey: "materialQuantity")
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsAmount!.text, forKey: "materialAmount")
        let realm = try! Realm()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(saveMaterials)
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialDescription) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialQuantity) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialAmount) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialTotal) to Realm Database")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }
}

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ServiceProMaterialsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsTotal: UILabel!

    var spMaterialsRequest: Results<SPMaterialsRequest>?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "MaterialsCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MaterialsCell
            else {
                fatalError("Dequed Cell is not an instance of MaterialsCell")
        }

        cell.materialsDescription.text = ""
        cell.materialsQuantity.text = ""
        cell.materialsAmount.text = "" 

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom delegate, implement that delegate in your viewcontroller. Pass the delegate to the cell while dequeuing the cell and calling that delegate in textFieldDidEndEditing, like :

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

protocol CustomProtocol{
func textEntered(text : String,index:Int)
}

class MaterialsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsDescription: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsAmount: UITextField!

    var delegate : CustomProtocol?
    var index : Int?

    func saveMaterialsData() {
        let saveMaterials = SPMaterialsRequest()
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsDescription!.text, forKey: "materialDescriptiopn")
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsQuantity!.text, forKey: "materialQuantity")
        saveMaterials.setValue(self.materialsAmount!.text, forKey: "materialAmount")
        let realm = try! Realm()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(saveMaterials)
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialDescription) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialQuantity) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialAmount) to Realm Database")
                print("added \(saveMaterials.materialTotal) to Realm Database")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //Usage of custom protocol
        delegate?.textEntered(text : textField.text!,index:self.index!)
    }
}

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ServiceProMaterialsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate , CustomProtocol{
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var materialsTotal: UILabel!

    var spMaterialsRequest: Results<SPMaterialsRequest>?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "MaterialsCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MaterialsCell
            else {
                fatalError("Dequed Cell is not an instance of MaterialsCell")
        }
        //Do 1 and 2
        cell.delegate = self // 1
        cell.index = indexPath.row //2
        cell.materialsDescription.text = ""
        cell.materialsQuantity.text = ""
        cell.materialsAmount.text = "" 

        return cell
    }

   //Implementing CustomProtocol
   func textEntered(text : String,index:Int){
      materialsTotal.text = text
    }

}
```

Comment: I can do still do the addition of the quantity and the amount in the textFieldDidEndEditing func too right? or do i do that when I implement the custom protocol in my viewcontroller?

Comment: I'm also running into the issue of the addition itself. Attempting to use a for in loop causes the error 'Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' '. Not quite sure what it is I'm doing wrong. @Yusuf