# How to use a variable in a Label text in the interface builder with the storyboard (Swift 5)?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Please I need help, I searched everywhere on Internet but didn't found no answer.

How to use a variable in a Label text in the interface builder with the storyboard (Swift 5, Xcode 13) ?

To be more precise, I want from my IB to display in a label a string variable already initialized. How is it possible?

Thank you very much !

Comment: You create an outlet (IBOutlet) in your code to the label and then use that property like any normal property when assigning a value to it

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to modify ma label with nameLabel.text = "" (it apparently works just with buttons)...

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong but it is not easy to know what, search for similar questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854831/update-label-text-at-runtime)) or some tutorial

Comment: @GhalySekkat - It's not clear what you are asking... Are you talking about setting the text of the Label ***in Storyboard*** to the value of a variable? Or, setting the text of the Label ***while your app is running***?

Comment: Setting the text of the Label while your app is running

Comment: @GhalySekkat - *"while your app is running"* -- OK, that is one of the most **basic** things to do. If it's not working, then you have either not connected the label to `@IBOutlet` correctly, or your code is wrong. Edit your question and provide more details on how you have connected the label and what code you've written to set its `.text`.

Comment: I wrote :
myLabel.text = "example" PS :
myLabel is perfectly connected with IBOutlet etc

Comment: @GhalySekkat - *where* did you write that? If you really want help, please take a few minutes to review [ask].

Comment: I wrote that in my View Controller in my class ViewController (and i said it's perfectly connected because there is the little gray point).

Answer (score -1):

In macOS the solution would be to use

```objectivec
NSString * variable = @"variable string";
kTextField_label.cell.text = variable;
```